# Get a square region of earth

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have a certain region given by the coordinates of the lefttop corner and bottom right corner. However, the region formed is not square since the radius of the circle decreases as the latitude increases. In my case, there is a difference of 3-4 km when I calculate the distance using top two coordinates and the bottom two coordinates So, how can I get a square region. I can't suppose that the the region bounded by the lefttop corner coordinate and bottomright coordinate is square. I want a region where the top two corners have a distance of x miles and the bottom two corners have a distance of x miles. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't into super-accuracy (ie the words WGS84 and oblate spheroid mean nothing to you) then it's simply a matter of calculating the km/degree of longitude at the upper latitude and then shifting the longitude of the two corners out a little, one east and one west.

Roughly:
Latitude: 1 deg = 110.54 km
Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320*cos(latitude) km

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude

Comment: Yeah that is the easiest of ways, But that will lead me to having four different coordinates for the four corners.

Comment: Yes. It is inevitable, except for a square placed symmetrically across the equator. You can't otherwise have four points on a square aligned to lat-long with two lat and two long values.

Answer (score 1):

Being precise, you cannot have square region on sphere surface. If you correct the distance of top 2 coordinates, then the "right" angles will not be 90 degrees and who knows if the vertical sides would be straight lines!

Google maps projection naturally gives you square in [lat, lon] 2D space, which is correct for most purposes - I also use this geographical "rectangle" grid of 11x11km squares on small spatial scales (400x200km) with no problems. If you neglect the small difference, your life will be much much easier. If you don't, I really cannot assure you the problem of exact rectangle on sphere surface even has any solution!